# "psexec cmd /c" doesn't work when using @file instead of \\CLIENT1

Tags: psexec

I would like to run `hostname` on a remote machine **CLIENT1**. If I provide the hostname with a UNC path directly in the `psexec` command it works fine as you can see below.

`psexec \\CLIENT1 -e cmd /c hostname`

```
CLIENT1 
cmd exited on CLIENT1 with error code 0.
```

If I choose to use the *@file* parameter of `psexec` to pass in a text file with the hostname, it doesn't run the `hostname` command.  It simply drops me in the `cmd` on the remote machine and stops executing.

`psexec @"c:\temp\hostname.txt" -e cmd /c hostname`

I can manually run `hostname` once I'm in there, but that's not what I'm after. 
 I either have to `exit` or `Ctrl-C`.

I've tried every combination of quotes that I can think of and nothing has worked.  Is this a bug?  Can anyone reproduce this behavior?  I'm running psexec v2.2 on Windows 7 SP1 (both local and remote), but also saw the behavior in psexec v2.11 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the path to the file containing the hostnames absolutely cannot be quoted.  This means your file of hostnames had better not have any spaces in the path.  I'm not sure if this is intended or not, but I sure lost a lot of time chasing it down.

**BAD**

```
psexec @"c:\temp\hostname.txt" -e cmd /c hostname
psexec @"hostname.txt" -e cmd /c hostname
```

**GOOD**

```
psexec @c:\temp\hostname.txt -e cmd /c hostname
psexec @hostname.txt -e cmd /c hostname
psexec @..\..\..\Temp\hostname.txt cmd /c hostname
psexec @\Temp\hostname.txt`
```

Answer (score -1):

PsExec \@Filename.txt -s cmd -u user

Comment: Try to explain what you are doing and why you thinks this may help (Bonus: try to use formatting)